# Star Wars Tangibility of Trans-hyperspace

Tags: star-wars, hyperspace, the-last-jedi

### ===========================>[Spoilers]

So after seeing TLJ a question started to plague me about the tangibility of trans hyperspace. In other words how tangible an object is when transitioning to hyperspace.
[image: Hyperspace Illistration]

This is how I have always thought of it. According to starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace There have been several instances where ships have jumped into and out of a planetary atmosphere. If you watch the sources you see little to no atmospheric disturbance meaning the air is not forced out of way of a fast moving object like atmospheric entry vehicles(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry). I always assumed this must because the transition to hyperspace (A different dimension) must cause the object to be mostly intangible, due to the nature of exiting physical space. TLJ proved this preconception was wrong, when Vice Admiral Amilyn Holdo engaged the hyperdrive of the last command ship directly into the path of the First Order Mega-class Star Destroyer, the Supremacy, heavily damaging it.

So I was wondering if someone could answer how this maneuver is possible or why exiting/entering hyperspace in side an atmosphere does not result in very high atmospheric disturbance if not nuclear fusion.

Willing to accept speculations but if possible please cite your "canon" sources.

Edit: Another example where trans-hyperspace passes through objects is Hera Syndulla while fleeing Lothal in a U-wing, jumped to hyperspace right in front of an Imperial construction module and flew through the hangar, successfully getting out the other side and making the jump."[Star Wars Rebels – "Kindred]

Comment: uncommon - Why do you say that star ships accelerate to the speed of light to enter hyperspace?   Whoever first made such a statement, whether the writer of a novel or a technical manual, or you just now, was being uncommonly stupid.  The whole point of warp drive or hyperspace travel is to avoid doing the impossible by accelerating to the speed or light or past it in normal space.  The relativity equations show that it would take infinite energy to accelerate even a single electron up to the speed of light.  Ships that impossibly reach the speed of light negate the point of hyperspace.

Comment: Alright lets say they dont approach light speed. They approach some kind of speed right? Enough to cause the Holdo maneuver. I am asking why those does not effect atmospheres.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, after posting my original answer below, I settled in to read *Legends: Lost Tribe Of the Sith: Precipice* and came across this passage (emphasis mine):

> In normal space, all the grenades, bombs, and other pleasantries, ... would have gone up in a flourish, taking the ship with it. But instead the armory had simply vanished - along with an impressive chuck of *Omen*'s quarterdeck. **The physics in hyperspace were unpredictable by definition**; instead of exploding outward, the breached deck simple left the ship in a seismic tug. Korsin could imagine the erupting munitions dropping out of hyperspace light-years behind the *Omen*.

This is *legends*, not *canon* but it lends evidence to your theory that matter in normal space and matter in hyperspace do not interact according to the laws of physics as we know them.

---

Generally speaking, I don't think the "science" in Star Wars was meant to be explainable.

As an out-of-universe explanation, the Star Wars franchise has a long history of explaining the *"what"* (schematic diagrams of lightsabers and x-wings, etc) but, unlike other sci-fi franchises, they pretty much stay clear of the *"how"*. The "magic-y" feel of the tech leads to the perspective that Star Wars is better classified as ***fantasy* not *science fiction***. [This blog post](https://simondillonbooks.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-star-wars-is-not-science-fiction-and-related-matters/) does a nice job of summing it up:

> Let’s be completely clear on this: Star Wars is not science fiction. It is fantasy; a fairy tale that happens to be set in space.
>
> I once explained the difference this way. In *Star Trek*, the Enterprise goes to warp speed because of some confusing gobbledegook about dilithium crystals, quantum tunnels, inertial dampeners and the warp drive. In *Star Wars*, the Millennium Falcon goes to light speed because it *can*. How it goes to light speed is utterly, utterly irrelevant in a story concerned with fairy tale themes.

---

**TL;DR: You have noticed that the details of how hyperspace works are never really explained, and if we try to apply real-world physics to it then there are inconsistencies. I think you're hunting for an answer where none exists.**

Comment: Yes I agree. Star Wars is not science fiction. The part that gets me is if X + Y = Z is proven a few times. Why is X + Y = A this time? But like you said none of us, really know how it works.

Comment: What's your evidence that X + Y = Z has been demonstrated before? It's certainly well-established that you can't hyperspace through solid matter (planets, stars, black holes, force fields, etc) without blowing yourself up. Your atmosphere example is a bit hazy at best (pun intended). Do you have others?

Comment: "The Clone Wars, a cruiser carrying an injured Anakin Skywalker had its hyperdrive accidentally triggered while still in a planet's atmosphere due to damage from droid fighters, and despite the proximity to the planet the ship successfully jumped to hyperspace without being destroyed. [Star Wars: The Clone Wars – "Jedi Crash"]    ---  "Jyn Erso and her company managed to jump into hyperspace from inside the atmosphere of Jedha after the Death Star destroyed the moon's Holy city." [Rogue One: A Star Wars Story]

Comment: "Hera Syndulla while fleeing Lothal in a U-wing, jumped to hyperspace right in front of an Imperial construction module and flew through the hangar, successfully getting out the other side and making the jump."[Star Wars Rebels – "Kindred] <== Actually the last one kind of proved that you can go through solid objects.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, kinda reads like she threaded the needle. Either way, hyperspacing through gasses seems fine while hyperspacing through solids (and especially gravity wells, less so). I feel like this is one of those cases where the SW universe was just never meant to be poked at this deeply.

Comment: I guess Ill just leave as it effects state of matter differently.

Comment: Sounds like hyperspace is as much of a mystery as the force. Now I'm curious who was the first person to discover hyperspace and how they did it, haha. Not sure Lucas ever even thought about that though.

Comment: This is not cannon but in the expanded universe there are space fairing animals that use there own biology to go into hyperspace. And I think it was the Builders mentioned in KOTOR that invented hyperspace engines.